# SQL - Get top 10 Usernames starting with a Letter

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a long list of usersNames. And I'm trying to get the first 10 usernames starting with A, B, C, D ... using Visual Studio c# with a local DB.

```
SELECT  tmpA.UserName, tmpB.UserName ...
FROM (  
SELECT top 10 [UserName]
FROM [Users]
WHERE UserName LIKE 'A%'
) tmpA,
(  
SELECT top 10 [UserName] 
FROM [Users]
WHERE UserName LIKE 'B%'
) tmpB
```

I'm trying to get a result looking like this:

```
a   | b   | c   ...
aa  | bb  | cc  ....
aaa | bbb | ccc ...
```

Where Column 1 has the first 10 usernames starting with "A", Second column has the first 10 usernames starting with "B" ect.

Hopefully one of you can help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your code is using SQL Server conventions, yet you have tagged the question with mysql.  What database are you really using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this using window functions and `pivot` or conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when left(name, 1) = 'a' then name end) as name_a,
       max(case when left(name, 1) = 'b' then name end) as name_b,
       . . .
       max(case when left(name, 1) = 'z' then name end) as name_z
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(name, 1) order by name) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10
group by seqnum
```

Comment: This seems to do the job. Thank you for taking the time to make it 99% copy paste-able.